# Proof of bound an optimal solution of minimum problem with strong convexity and smoothness

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent, smooth-functions, strong-convergence

I am studying this [set of notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/tss/files/papers/1506.08187.pdf). In 1.2 they proof
[the creation of a ball with the optimal solution (x*) inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXfjp.png).
I am having difficulties to undertsand how the betha-strong convexity of f implies the first ball and how the alpha-smoothness implies te second one.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result is obtained by completing the square technique. Consider the definition of strong convexity:
$$f(y)\geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y - x) + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x\|^2, \qquad \forall x,y.$$
If you move the inner product inside the norm, you get
$$f(y)\geq f(x) +  \frac{\alpha}{2}\|y-x + \frac{1}{\alpha}\nabla f(x)\|^2 - \frac{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}{2\alpha}, \qquad \forall x,y.$$
Rearrangement of terms yields
$$\frac{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}{\alpha^2} -\frac{2}{\alpha}(f(x) - f(y))\geq  \|y-x + \frac{1}{\alpha}\nabla f(x)\|^2, \qquad \forall x,y.$$
Now substitution of $y = x^\star$ and $x^{++} = x  - \frac{1}{\alpha}\nabla f(x)$ gives
$$\frac{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}{\alpha^2} -\frac{2}{\alpha}(f(x) - f(x^\star))\geq  \|x^\star-x^{++}\|^2, \qquad \forall x$$
which implies
$$x^\star \in \mathbb{B}\left(x^{++}, \frac{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}{\alpha^2} -\frac{2}{\alpha}(f(x) - f(x^\star))\right).$$
To obtain the second identity, you need to replace $f(x)$ with its lower bound given in the note.